# CSS3: Adjust height of iframe to fit its content

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am new to CSS and therefore the solution to this question might be simple. I have searched the web but found no solution; despite the fact that I think this problem is fairly common.

I am embedding an iframe into a html document, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test</p>
    <iframe class=result-frame src="/media/converted/1409487227933_testpage.html></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to make the iframe as big as necessary to enclose all its content. For this purpose I set the width to 100%:

```
.result-frame {
   width: 100%;
}
```

But I don't know how I can adjust the height of the iframe to be big enough to fit its content, so that no scrollbars are displayed.

I have seen some solution using javascript, but I would like to stick to CSS/HTML only. Is this even possible?

Tobias

Comment: No, that is not possible with HTML and CSS only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with CSS. And there is more, iframes will work different way in different browsers. If you see it on Safari from al iPad, you will see the iframe as you want, the 100% height. There is a bug right there that people solve enclosing it in a container and setting `overflow-y: scroll;` but not in other browsers.

What you can do is get the body's height by javascript and set the same height for the iframe.
Here is a piece of code that will work, I am using jQuery here but you can do it without jQuery:

```
$('#iframe-id').height( $('#iframe-id').contents().find('body').height() );
```

Assuming that your body's height is the full height of your `iframe`, if you used floating elements and you didn't clear the iframe you will have problems.

You can also use `html` tag:

```
$('#iframe-id').height( $('#iframe-id').contents().find('html').height() );
```